# How MVC razor manages TempData value at the client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, tempdata

Currently I have started using MVC 4 Razor.
I want to know that "Where TempData is handled if assign its value in javascript?"

For example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                        

        function removeTempDataValue()
        {
            @{TempData["a"] = null;}
            @{TempData["b"] = null;}
        }
    </script>
```

Now in this case, I will call `removeTempDataValue()` function on click of one div.
So i want to know that how MVC4 razor will set `TempData`'s value.

So how it will manage `TempData`'s value client side?

Answer (score 4):

> So i want to know that how MVC4 razor will set TempData's value.

TempData is purely server side. So when you do that you are basically removing the value at the server. Javascript runs much later, on the client. Things like click events run on the client and you cannot manipulate TempData at all.

> So how it will manage TempData's value client side?

It won't manage anything client side. If you want to change some value in TempData this can only happen at the server side. If you want to modify some server side value from the client you could use an AJAX request.

Comment: :: `If you want to modify some server side value from the client you could use an AJAX request.` this does change the value of TempData. I gets updated data at the server side , if it is set by above as I mentioned in my post. Kindly correct me if I have misunderstood your reply.